# Creating a dynamic tableLayout in a thread

Tags: android, dynamic, loading, tablelayout

I want to create a dynamic table layout in a thread (because I have a huge table and loading is quite long). It seems to work till the fourth row but after an error appears.

I can't find where the issue is. In this java code, the table layout has been simplified to fund the issue.

My java code :

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity implements Runnable {

    private TextView tv;
    private ProgressDialog pd;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.main1);
            tv.setText("Press any key to start calculation");

            pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Working..", "Calculating", true,false);

            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();

    }

    public void run() {
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tdyn);

            TableRow row=null;
            TextView label = null;

            int size=10;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                row = new TableRow(this);
                //row.setId(100+i);
                row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 


                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                    Log.i("Test",Integer.toString(i) + "-" + Integer.toString(j));
                    label = new TextView(this);
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(i) + "-" + Integer.toString(j) + " ");
                    label.setLayoutParams(new  TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                    label.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    row.addView(label);
                }

                if(i%2==0)
                    row.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
                else
                    row.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);

                table.addView(row);
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);


    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                pd.dismiss();

                    tv.setText("ok");

            }
    };



}
```

Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/main1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="test"
    />

    <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tdyn" android:background="#F87907" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                        <TableRow>
                            <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
                                android:text="test11"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                            <TextView android:id="@+id/info"
                                android:text="test12"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                        </TableRow>
                   </TableLayout>
                   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your help

```
Edit : You can find the the logcat :


09-12 12:06:57.973: INFO/Test(215): 8-1
09-12 12:06:57.973: INFO/Test(215): 8-2
09-12 12:06:57.983: INFO/Test(215): 8-3
09-12 12:06:57.993: INFO/Test(215): 8-4
09-12 12:06:58.003: INFO/Test(215): 8-5
09-12 12:06:58.003: INFO/Test(215): 8-6
09-12 12:06:58.012: INFO/Test(215): 8-7
09-12 12:06:58.024: INFO/Test(215): 8-8
09-12 12:06:58.024: INFO/Test(215): 8-9
09-12 12:06:58.044: WARN/dalvikvm(215): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
09-12 12:06:58.044: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-8 exiting due to uncaught exception
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2683)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:557)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:7918)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.widget.TableLayout.requestLayout(TableLayout.java:223)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1754)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:418)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1713)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:400)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1693)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:391)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at com.sil.DialogActivity.run(DialogActivity.java:65)
09-12 12:06:58.073: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(215):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-12 12:06:58.102: INFO/Process(52): Sending signal. PID: 215 SIG: 3
09-12 12:06:58.102: INFO/dalvikvm(215): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
09-12 12:06:58.102: ERROR/dalvikvm(215): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
09-12 12:06:58.464: INFO/ARMAssembler(52): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x546c90:0x546d4c] in 655949 ns
09-12 12:06:58.663: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Displayed activity com.sil/.DialogActivity: 4121 ms (total 4121 ms)
```

Comment: what is the problem elaborate it. and also update Logcat

Comment: can't you use gridview for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. First of all, I cannot use gridview I have a table of more than 200 rows and about 20 columns. I'll post the logcat.

Comment: I just want to ass,that it works for size=3, butnot for size=10. (if it can help) to find the issue :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try out the code written below.There is some modification from your current code.All the things are generated dynamically through code only.

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout mainLayout;
    private LinearLayout innerLayout;
    private TextView tv;
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private int size = 10;
    private int increment = 0;
    private TableLayout table;
    private Context context;
    private TableRow row;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        context = this;

        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        mainLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        innerLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        innerLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        innerLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText("Press any key to start calculation");

        table = new TableLayout(context);
        table.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        table.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F87907"));

        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("Calculating");
        pd.setTitle("Working....");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setMax(size);
        pd.show();

        ThreadRender thread = new ThreadRender();
        thread.start();

    }

    private class ThreadRender extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            TextView label = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                row = new TableRow(context);
                // row.setId(100+i);
                row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    Log.i("Test",
                            Integer.toString(i) + "-" + Integer.toString(j));
                    label = new TextView(context);
                    label.setText(Integer.toString(i) + "-"
                            + Integer.toString(j) + " ");
                    label.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                    label.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
                    row.addView(label);
                }

                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    row.setBackgroundColor(0xff222222);
                } else {
                    row.setBackgroundColor(0xff000000);
                }
                table.addView(row);
                increment++;
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(101);
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(102);
        }
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 102:
                innerLayout.addView(tv);
                innerLayout.addView(table);
                mainLayout.addView(innerLayout);
                setContentView(mainLayout);
                pd.dismiss();
                tv.setText("ok");
                break;
            case 101:
                Log.i("Test", " " + increment);
                pd.setProgress(increment);
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! 
It seems to work, I will check it in more details tonight (I'm located in France). I will add my comments and will set your answer as my accepted answer.

Thank you ! :-)

Comment: What is the aim of the line : Looper.prepare();  please ?

Comment: Basically it is used for Message Loop.Please refer this link (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) for more use.

Comment: Thank you.
I will be able to test this code deeper in 7hours :-) !